# androidTest with composeRule coroutines cancellation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, android-viewmodel

I am trying to run a simple compose ui test. I am setting it up like this:

```
@Before
fun setUp(){

    hiltRule.inject()
    composeRule.activity.setContent {
        ApolloTheme {
            Navigator(CharactersListScreen())
        }
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
@Test
fun onClick() {


        composeRule.onNodeWithTag(TestTags.SEARCH_FIELD).performTextInput("Anything")
        composeRule.onNodeWithContentDescription("Search").performClick()

        composeRule.waitUntilAtLeastOneExists(hasTestTag("1"), 5000)

        composeRule.onNodeWithTag("1").assertIsDisplayed()

}
```

CharactersListScreen contains viewmodel.

The problem is suspend functions of the viewmodel does not seem to work correctly.
Calling delay() immediately cancels the coroutine:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@8ff2fb5
```

Also when updating state value ...

```
fun updateSearchQuery(value : String) {

    searchQuery.value = value
}
```

... the new value is not collected:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
val charactersPagingFlow = searchQuery.flatMapLatest { query ->
    getNewCharactersPagingFlow(query )
}.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Works though when I am launching my whole activity. Not setting content